# How to get the next result for the right paginating

Tags: javascript, sqlite, asp-classic, pagination

I need to know how to use exactlly the `paginating function`.
I have read that `offest` isn't the only way, and there an many ways to `paginating` between the results. 
I would like to `paginating` without reload the site it's possible?

I got this example

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 100, 5000
```

I expect to put it in a `function` or in `<a>` or in `button` + `Eventlistener`...
I don't get it how to displaying the next number of result and next on. 
Hope what i try to explain is clear.
Thx for the help.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results is good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic asp indeed, then you can make use of the recordset pagination features.

You might want to have a look at this tutorial: [ADO Recordset paging in ASP](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619/ADO-Recordset-Paging-in-ASP)